# HTML dentro d HTML

Tags: html, css

Estou com uma duvida aqui.

Possuo o seguinte código em HTML:

```
<html>

    <head>

        <?php

    $logado =  'my name';

    ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cabecalho.css"/>

<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <yp><?php echo '<p>'.$logado.'</p>'; ?></yp>
        <li><a href="/projetos/index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/projetos/historico.php">Histórico</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Em breve</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Em breve</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Em breve</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav> 
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Como é possível ver estou chamando as características da página por um arquivo Css

Queria saber se é possível montar um arquivo que contenha

```
<nav> 
<ul>
        <yp><?php echo '<p>'.$logado.'</p>'; ?></yp>
        <li><a href="/projetos/index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/projetos/historico.php">Histórico</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Em breve</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Em breve</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Em breve</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

e que eu insira dentro da página de uma forma semelhante com o css?

Tipo:

```
<html>

    <head>

        <?php

    $logado =  'my name';

    ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cabecalho.css"/>

<link chamar 'nav' aqui dentro/> 
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Nao deu pra entender o que voce quer, poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Que confuso. Nada fez muito sentido, mas quem sabe seria algo que o [`include`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php) do PHP resolvesse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Header.php

<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <yp><?php echo '<p>'.$logado.'</p>'; ?></yp>
        <li><a href="/projetos/index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/projetos/historico.php">Histórico</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Em breve</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Em breve</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Em breve</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Agora nos arquivos que quer incluir use

```
<?php
   require("Header.php");
?>
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso, muito obrigado Rafael

Answer (score 2):

Se entendi corretamente, faça o seguinte:

Crie um arquivo .php contendo toda sua *nav* e chame esse arquivo onde quiser utilizando o método include ou require do php.